# Radius Map with Points

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to create a radius map around our coordinates. I took the sample map for creating circles on Google's API database and tweaked the code to make it do what I wanted it to do. I am very unfamiliar with Google Maps API and coding in general, so its very possible that I may have a few errors in my coding or that I may have done some things that are completely unnecessary to make the map work, but it does seem to work correctly thus far.

However, now my next step is that I need to add a simple points for specific coordinates within each of my radius circles, but cannot seem to figure out how to do this. Google maps has sample coding for simple points, just like the circles, but I cannot see where this should be added into my coding, in order to make this work. Please help! Coding is posted below. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pickup and Delivery</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
// This example creates circles on the map, representing
// populations in North America.

// First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
var citymap = {};
citymap['Area1'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
  population: 10000
};
citymap['Area2'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
  population: 40000
};
citymap['Area3'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
  population: 90000
};
citymap['Area4'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
  population: 160000
};
citymap['Area5'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
  population: 250000
};
citymap['Area6'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
  population: 360000
};
citymap['Area7'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
  population: 490000
};
citymap['Area8'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
  population: 640000
};
citymap['Area9'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
  population: 810000
};
citymap['Area10'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
  population: 1000000
};
var cityCircle;

function initialize() {
  // Create the map.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.420936, -82.860795),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#0000',`enter code here`
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillOpacity: 0.00,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What points do you want to add?  What questions do you have on the [documentation on adding markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)?

Comment: Seems like [**Markers**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) are the way to go. :)